# Enfocar un elemento al iterar sobre el

Tags: javascript, html5, dom

Estoy simulando un lector de pantalla para mi pagina web. Lo que hago es que agrego todos los elementos del DOM dentro de un array y luego cuando el usuario presiona cierta combinación de teclas itero en el array y usando la API de speechSynthesis de html5 genero el audio de acuerdo al texto que tenga dicho elemento.

El problema es que quiero que vaya haciendo `focus` en el elemento que estoy "reproduciendo".

El código con el cual genero el array de elementos:

```
function walkDOM(main) {
    var arr = [];
    var loop = function(main) {

        do {

            if(main.hasChildNodes())
                loop(main.firstChild);
            else if(main.nodeName === "IFRAME"){
                var documentIframe = main.contentWindow.document;
                loop(documentIframe.getElementsByTagName("body")[0]);
            }
            else if(main.nodeName !== "#comment") {
                arr.push(main);
            }
        }
        while (main = main.nextSibling);

    };
    loop(main);
    return arr;
}
```

Y con esto me encargo de iterar en el arreglo que obtengo cuando el usuario preciona `ctrl` + `space`

```
function PulsarTecla(e) {   
    var e = e || event;

    if(e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 32){
        allElements = walkDOM(document.body);
        console.log(allElements);
        for(var i = 0; i < allElements.length; i++){
            console.log(allElements[i])
            allElements[i].parentNode.focus(); // hago focus en el padre del texto sin embargo no aparece nada en pantalla

            habla(allElements[i].textContent);



        }
    }
}
```

La función que se encarga de "hablar"

```
function habla(palabra) {
        speech = window.speechSynthesis;
        voz = speechSynthesis.getVoices()[3];
        utterThis = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(palabra, voz, 1, 1);
        speechSynthesis.speak(utterThis);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Primero deberías comprobar que el elemento que quieres que reciba el foco es susceptible de ese estado.

Aquí explicaron qué elementos puede recibirlo y su comportamiento: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1599660/which-html-elements-can-receive-focus

En caso contrario, creo que deberías hacer esos cambios con CSS, por ejemplo ponerle un fondo y quitarlo cuando vaya a pasar a la siguiente sílaba.